# Powering a microcontroller circuit using a differential voltage instead of an absolute voltage

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, voltage

So this is a more theoretical question. Imagine I have 2 perfect power supplies that I can set to whatever voltage I feel like (10 000 VDC for example).

Now I know that when it comes to voltage it's the potential difference that you actually use (e.g 10 V on GND and 15 V on V<sub>CC</sub> gives the chip 5 V).

As an example, imagine I have a simple microcontroller circuit with the correct track spacing and width. If I put 10 000 V on the V<sub>CC</sub> pin and 9995 V on the GND pin of the circuit, would it still power up? Would there be some other adverse effects if I was to implement this practically or would it be no different to using 5 V and 0 VDC.
Is it the same using negative voltages (-9995 V on V<sub>CC</sub> and -10 000 V on GND)?

My main question is, could you power a circuit using whatever voltage you wanted as long as the difference between the voltages is the same as the component ratings (e.g 5 V)? I know in theory the maths says "Yes" but practically would it be any different?

*I want to reiterate, I am not actually planning to power a circuit with 10 000 V so no "You're going to die using that voltage" please.*

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's all relative. Even your hypothetical 10,000V is relative to some other "ground". There is no absolute zero voltage.

Comment: Yes, pratically you have to consider tolerances of components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, in fact, people do it every day. Often a mains powered H-bridge will use an isolated high side gate driver, so running at 340v and 15v above that.

What people do is implement the two different voltages by setting one relative to the other, for tolerances and for practicality.

Tolerance. Consider that you had a 10kV power supply and a 9995v supply, and that they were both very very good tolerance, say 0.1%. Their difference would be 5v +/- 20v, anything from -15v to +25v. Not a nice environment for your 5v chip!

Practicality. Why make two different standalone 10kV power supplies, twice as expensive as a single supply, when most of the time what's needed is a cheap 5v supply 'riding on' the 10kV.

For a low current supply, your 10kV supply could use a current leak to ground through a big resistor, and use a 5v zener to regulate the 9995v with respect to the 10kV.

For any serious power at 10kV, it would be less wasteful to use an isolation transformer, to supply a rectifier and 5v regulator at 10kV.

The mains powered high side driver often uses a charge pump capacitor, as it doesn't need full isolation from the low side, and needs a reasonable amount of power.

Answer (score 2):

No problem at all. There is not even any reason why the voltage offset from earth potential has to be constant, it could be constantly varying as long as it was at a low frequency in comparison to the operating speed of the system and both rails moved in exactly the same way.

You do however have the obvious issues involved with interfacing it to anything, you would need some sort of high voltage isolation between it and anything else including any users.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and you can even do what you propose on a high-voltage AC system but there are a few practical considerations:

- The PCB would have to be adequately isolated from earth and other circuits connected to it otherwise sparks would jump the gap, high currents would flow and the device would be destroyed.

[image]

*Figure 1. [Optx OPI268s](http://optekinc.com/datasheets/opi1268s.pdf) high-voltage opto-isolator provides 20 kV isolation and 30 kV/µs dV/dt immunity with a creepage path (across the circuit board or case of device) of > 24 mm. (Pin centres are 25 mm.)*

- All connections to the device including opto-isolators and signal transformers, etc., would require adequate voltage rating. e.g., A regular opto-isolator would have only 1000 V rating.
- The board and isolation devices would require low capacitance to ground to prevent problems during operation but also during power-up when the voltage is changing.
- A suitable 5 V supply would be used to generate a stable 5 V supply with the 0 V line "grounded" at whatever potential made sense for the application. This would be much better than trying to generate a 10000 V and 10005 V supply directly as it would be extremely difficult to maintain the difference of exactly 5 V during operation and particularly during power-up.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider that the micro is powered from a battery and totally unconnected galvanically to anything. Depending where it sits in relation to your house AC wiring it might be internally rising up and down at tens or hundreds of volts relative to real ground at the frequency of your AC power. Nothing terrible happens unless the circuit board on which your micro sits is really badly designed.

And this is the crux of the problem. A really bad PCB might have different parts of its circuit offering significantly different capacitance to ground and, if say the household AC were switched on when the voltage was at a peak, there would be a substantial rate of change of voltage of maybe hundreds of volts per microsecond.

Because, for a capacitor Q = CV, both sides can be differentiated to give: -

\$\dfrac{dQ}{dT} = C\dfrac{dV}{dt}\$ and this equals current flow in the capacitor.

So, a massive value for dv/dt can induce a current flow in one part of a circuit board significantly different to another part and this will give rise to a differential voltage that *could* cause the circuit to malfunction or become damaged. Not at all uncommon.

So, going back to your 10,000 volt supply and your 9,995 volt supply, just a minor glitch of 0.01% on one supply will shift the relative voltage by 1 whole volt. Probably not enough to kill a micro but maybe enough to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Birds do this every day when they land on high voltage transmission lines, its is all about relativity. As long as the bird goes (in voltage) where their environment voltage goes, no harm done.

Comment: There is more to it that you seem to think. Read the other answers.